# Forwarding after successful login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-router

I want to forward the user after logging in correctly. I use React-router to resolve the Router paths.

I have tried various things which did not work *(see commented lines).*

Currently I am trying to use `history.push()`, but the compiler says

> history.push is not a function.

I noticed that the push method from `"redux-router"` is not used.. instead it probably looks for a method in the props, which does not exist.

How do I do that?

```
/**
 * Created by wding on 11/21/2016.
 */
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
    Grid,
    Row,
    Col,
    PageHeader,
    Well,
    Input,
    Panel,
    ButtonInput,
    Button,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    ControlLabel,
    FormControl,
    Checkbox
} from "react-bootstrap";
import {IndexLinkContainer, LinkContainer, Link, Redirect} from "react-router-bootstrap";
import browserHistory from "react-router";
import * as LoginControllerActions from "../actions/LoginController"
import {connect, dispatch} from "react-redux";
import {push,pushState} from "redux-router";

export class StartPage extends React.Component {
    getResearcher(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value;
        var password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value;
        console.log(username, password);

       // this.props.login(username, password);
        // this.context.history.transitionTo('/ExperimentDashboard');
        const {history} = this.props;
        console.log("history",history);
        history.push('/ExperimentDashboard');
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
        }
    }
          //  console.log('Attempt to push state')
            //history.pushState(null, '/ExperimentDashboard');
            //history.go(-1);
        //   browserHistory.push('/ExperimentDashboard');

    render(){

        return (
            <Form horizontal>
                <div>
                    <Col md={8}>
                        All experiments
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={4}>
                        <Panel header="Login for Researchers">
                            <div style={{
                                "paddingLeft": "25px",
                                "paddingRight": "25px"
                            }}>
                                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel}>
                                        Name
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col >
                                        <FormControl type="username" placeholder="Name"
                                                     ref="username"/>
                                    </Col>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel}>
                                        Password
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password"
                                                     ref="password"/>
                                    </Col>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Col>
                                        {/*<LinkContainer to="/ExperimentDashboard">*/}
                                        <Button type="submit" onClick={this.getResearcher.bind(this)}>
                                            Log in
                                        </Button>
                                        {/*</LinkContainer>*/}
                                    </Col>
                                </FormGroup>
                            </div>
                        </Panel>
                    </Col>
                </div>
            </Form>
        )
    }

}

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {
        login:{formState:{username, password},isLoggedIn},
        router
    } = state;
    return {username, password,router,history,isLoggedIn};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    login: LoginControllerActions.login,

};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StartPage);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never used `redux-router` so just using logic, have you checked if `history` is a prop of `router`? You're setting that in your `mapStateToProps` function so maybe `router.history.push` is the correct method?

Comment: You should be able to call "this.props.router.push(...)" or "browserHistory.push(...)". Did you set up your <Router /> correctly? Maybe paste it here so we can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate via push and replace action creators with redux-router: See [Link](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router#pushlocation).

Like this:

```
import { push } from 'redux-router';

// Somewhere in code
push('/orders/' + order.id));

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    login: LoginControllerActions.login,
    push
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about adding push to mapDispatchToProps

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake lies in the import statement.
Replace it with:

```
 import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```